# Update values on table reverse order (Postgresql)

Tags: postgresql

I have a table with three columns (way_id, node_id, sequence_id) with a unique constraint on way_id and sequence_id.

If I want to insert an item at row 10, I want to increase all those with a sequence_id >= 10 by +1. Running the SQL command causes a violation error. I understand why but I don't know where to begin to work around it.

```
UPDATE public.current_way_nodes
SET sequence_id = sequence_id + 1
WHERE way_id = 1025063 AND sequence_id >= 10
```

I've tried SQL similar to below that reverses the update order but it says that it cannot find 'm' on the first line. I've also tried "WITH m AS (..." and it says that it cannot find m. I'm at a complete loss.

```
UPDATE m
SET sequence_id = sequence_id + 1
FROM (
  Select  *
  FROM public.current_way_nodes
  WHERE way_id = 1025063 AND sequence_id >= 10
  ORDER BY sequence_id DESC
) m
```

Original

```
way_id node_id sequence_id
1025063 2248594 1
1025063 1591653 2
1025063 1591652 3
1025063 1591651 4
1025063 1591650 5
1025063 1591649 6
1025063 1591648 7
1025063 1591647 8
1025063 1591646 9
1025063 1591645 10
1025063 1591644 11
1025063 1591643 12
1025063 1591642 13
1025063 1591641 14
1025063 2248596 15
```

Desired

```
way_id node_id sequence_id
1025063 2248594 1
1025063 1591653 2
1025063 1591652 3
1025063 1591651 4
1025063 1591650 5
1025063 1591649 6
1025063 1591648 7
1025063 1591647 8
1025063 1591646 9
**NO ENTRY AT ROW 10**
1025063 1591645 11
1025063 1591644 12
1025063 1591643 13
1025063 1591642 14
1025063 1591641 15
1025063 2248596 16
```

--

```
-- Table: public.current_way_nodes

-- DROP TABLE IF EXISTS public.current_way_nodes;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public.current_way_nodes
(
    way_id bigint NOT NULL,
    node_id bigint NOT NULL,
    sequence_id bigint NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT current_way_nodes_pkey PRIMARY KEY (way_id, sequence_id),
    CONSTRAINT current_way_nodes_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (way_id)
        REFERENCES public.current_ways (id) MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION
        ON DELETE NO ACTION,
    CONSTRAINT current_way_nodes_node_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (node_id)
        REFERENCES public.current_nodes (id) MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION
        ON DELETE NO ACTION
)

TABLESPACE pg_default;

ALTER TABLE IF EXISTS public.current_way_nodes
    OWNER to user;
-- Index: current_way_nodes_node_idx

-- DROP INDEX IF EXISTS public.current_way_nodes_node_idx;

CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS current_way_nodes_node_idx
    ON public.current_way_nodes USING btree
    (node_id ASC NULLS LAST)
    TABLESPACE pg_default;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot update a derived table, because it's transient. Even if you could, the `UPDATE` wouldn't necessarily respect the `ORDER BY` in the subselect.

What you want is a [deferrable primary key constraint](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtable.html), which will be validated at the end of the transaction:

```
...
CONSTRAINT current_way_nodes_pkey PRIMARY KEY (way_id, sequence_id) 
 DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
...
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=be552c50e4e542b34e5b4aa4065f772f)

---

PS. I was lucky to obtain the table DDL from your earlier, now deleted question. Consider adding it to this one.

Comment: Sorry for deleting it. I dropped the primary key and recreated it with the deferrable options you specifically. This worked a treat, thank you!